# Building game playable on one machine but not another

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I've built my first XNA game and when I go to the build folder and execute the exe it works fine, however when I send the game to a friend of mine, he is unable to play the game and it crashes on startup.

I've tested this on several machines, and they all seem to suffer from the same issue.

Is there something I need to do to get it builded correctly and working on other machines?

btw. I did make sure I copied over the content folder from the output directory too, so its not missing its contents.

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework 4: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851 Microsoft XNA Framework 4: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you will need to make sure the other computers have both the .NET and XNA Framework's installed. If you do a quick search on Google, you should be able to find the packages that you need, depending on what versions of the runtime's you are using.

For example, here are links to the downloads for the [.NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=65) and the [XNA Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20914).

Note that this may not be all the prerequisites that you need.

Comment: Right, that might explain why, however this means that xna framework has to be installed always on the client machine. I was hopping not needed to do that as I wanted to distribute it via something like Steam

Comment: @Lex, Steam automatically handles that for you. If you look at the steam title "Terraria" it's an XNA game on Steam.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could provide a more detailed description of what kind of crash it is :) Do they get some kind of error message?

Are you using any third party libraries in the build?

Also, the machines that should run the game will need the correct version of the .NET framework, as well as a more specific XNA framework install.

Have you tried letting the users install the XNA Framework Redistributable?
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20914

See if that fixes the crash :)

Comment: The questions would do better as comments on the original post, as opposed to being asked in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good bet that the person doesn't have the right version of the .NET framework or the right version of the XNA redistributable.

My first thought is to try [publishing your game with ClickOnce](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/using-clickonce-to-distribute-your-game) (full disclosure: that's a link to my site, but I think it's still relevant).

That makes it easy for both you and the people you share it with to get the right libraries to run your game.  To clarify, the other person does not need to install Visual Studio, Visual C# Express, or XNA Game Studio.  There's lightweight redistributable libraries that they need instead, which ClickOnce will figure out for you.

My second suggestion is that it is possible your machine is capable of handling the HiDef profile, while everyone else that you've shared your game with can only handle the Reach profile.  If that's your problem, you can change it to build for the Reach profile and fix that problem.  That's discussed here, half way through the tutorial: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-project-template

If neither of these suggestions help, please post any sort of stack trace or error message they're getting so that we can try to help you further.